# Clearing cache with CloudFlare?

Tags: wordpress, css, cache, cloudflare

Is it possible to clear or avoid CloudFlare cache while doing development?

I'm developing a site that has caching on several levels - WordPress supercache, the caching done by the browser, and caching through the DNS provider, CloudFlare (free account version).  I cannot seem to get my CSS to refresh, despite deleting the browser cache, deleting the WordPress supercache cache, & disabling caching (firefox web development toolbar), so I'm guessing the cached copy that remains is due to the DNS, but have no idea how to clear it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [development mode](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168246-What-does-CloudFlare-Development-mode-mean-). You can also manually [purge](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-) the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *https://www.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-settings* and then click on the tab called 'performance settings'. You will find all the options you need.